# Como llamar a metodo de controlador para cargar una vista parcial, desde vista

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Solicito de su ayuda, tengo el siguiente controlador el cual incluye 2 métodos:

```
       public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, int page = 1, int pageSize = 10, string sort = "Id", string sortdir = "DESC")
    {
            AlumnosModel oAlumnos = new AlumnosModel();
            using (TutoriasEntities dbTutorias = new TutoriasEntities())
            {
                var IdentificaAlumno = (from x in dbTutorias.vInfoTutorado_Tutoria_Alumno_Catalogos
                                        where x.id_tutorado == id
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            x.cve_unica,
                                            x.cnombre,
                                            x.capellido_paterno,
                                            x.capellido_materno,
                                            x.ccurp,
                                            x.ccorreo_personal,
                                            x.ctelefono,
                                            x.csexo
                                        }).FirstOrDefault();
                oAlumnos.cnombre_completo = IdentificaAlumno.cnombre + ", " + IdentificaAlumno.capellido_paterno + " " + IdentificaAlumno.capellido_materno;
                oAlumnos.cve_unica = IdentificaAlumno.cve_unica;
                oAlumnos.ccurp = IdentificaAlumno.ccurp;
                oAlumnos.ccorreo_personal = IdentificaAlumno.ccorreo_personal;
                oAlumnos.ctelefono = IdentificaAlumno.ctelefono;
                oAlumnos.csexo = IdentificaAlumno.csexo;
            }
            string imageBase64;
            using (FotografiasEntities dbFotos = new FotografiasEntities())
            {
                var iExisteReg = (from x in dbFotos.fotos_alumnos
                                  where x.cve_unica == oAlumnos.cve_unica
                                  select new { x.cve_unica, x.img_foto }).Count();

                if (iExisteReg > 0) // Si hay foto la carga
                {
                    var FotoAlumno = (from x in dbFotos.fotos_alumnos
                                      where x.cve_unica == oAlumnos.cve_unica
                                      select new { x.img_foto }).FirstOrDefault();
                    imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(FotoAlumno.img_foto);
                    oAlumnos.img_foto = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                }
                else
                {   // En caso de que no exista foto de alumno
                    if (oAlumnos.csexo == "M") // Foto para hombres M = Machos alfa
                    {
                        var FotoAlumnoAux = (from x in dbFotos.fotos_alumnos
                                             where x.cve_unica == "0000001"    // Cargamos foto de hombres = 0000001
                                             select new { x.img_foto }).FirstOrDefault();
                        imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(FotoAlumnoAux.img_foto);
                    }
                    else
                    {   // F = Feminazis
                        var FotoAlumnoAux = (from x in dbFotos.fotos_alumnos
                                             where x.cve_unica == "0000002"    // Cargamos foto de mujeres = 0000002
                                             select new { x.img_foto }).FirstOrDefault();
                        imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(FotoAlumnoAux.img_foto);
                    }
                    oAlumnos.img_foto = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                }

            }
            return View(oAlumnos);
    }

    public ActionResult MuestraHistorialIndividual(int id = 0)
    {
        int page = 1;
        int pageSize = 10;
        var _records = new PagedList<vHistorial_Individual_Coordinador>();
        ViewBag.filter = id;
        using (TutoriasEntities dbTutorias = new TutoriasEntities())
        {
            _records.Content = dbTutorias.vHistorial_Individual_Coordinador
                            .Where(x => x.id_tutorado == id)
                            .ToList();
        }
        _records.CurrentPage = page;
        _records.PageSize = pageSize;
        return View(_records);
    }
```

Mi problema consiste en que deseo llamar a los dos métodos en la vista, `Index` carga la vista con datos del usuario de un lado, mientras que del otro lado deseo se despliegue un historial este historial lo tengo en una vista parcial.

Como puede hacer para llamar al método `MuestraHistorialIndividual` desde la vista pasando le un parámetro ?, esta es mi vista:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Controlador = "Historial de Sesiones";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Tutorado(a)";
}

<h1>Ver sesiones de Tutorado(a)</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xlg-3">
        <div class="card">
            @Html.Partial("_MuestraPerfil")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xlg-9">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="well">
                < % Html.RenderPartial("MuestraHistorialIndividual", Model);  %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quiero llamar al método `MuestraHistorialIndividual` que llama a la vista parcial del mismo nombre, enviándole un ID, y así mostrar perfil en el lado izquierdo y en el lado derecho el detalle de historial de sesiones.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, debes devolver desde la Acción `MuestraHistorialIndividual(int id=0)` un **`PartialViewResult`** con el **nombre** de la Vista parcial a devolver:

```
public ActionResult MuestraHistorialIndividual(int id = 0)
{
    int page = 1;
    int pageSize = 10;
    var _records = new PagedList<vHistorial_Individual_Coordinador>();
    ViewBag.filter = id;
    using (TutoriasEntities dbTutorias = new TutoriasEntities())
    {
        _records.Content = dbTutorias.vHistorial_Individual_Coordinador
                        .Where(x => x.id_tutorado == id)
                        .ToList();
    }
    _records.CurrentPage = page;
    _records.PageSize = pageSize;

    return PartialView("_ElNombreDeTuVistaParcial", _records);
}
```

Luego en la Vista `Index`, llamas a la Acción `MuestraHistorialIndividual(int id=0)` para que te devuelva la Vista parcial con el Helper **`@Html.RenderAction()`**, indicando el nombre de la **Acción** y el **parámetro** `id`:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Controlador = "Historial de Sesiones";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  ViewBag.Title = "Tutorado(a)";
}

<h1>Ver sesiones de Tutorado(a)</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xlg-3">
        <div class="card">
            @Html.Partial("_MuestraPerfil")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xlg-9">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="well">

                @{
                    Html.RenderAction("MuestraHistorialIndividual", 
                                       new { id = 1 }); 
                 }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rafael!, amigo, estamos aprendiendo te agradezco la tolerancia. Rafael, se que seguro tendrás trabajo externo o personal, amigo... pero te cuestiono de casualidad has llevado a cabo capacitaciones personales ? obvio con costo...

Comment: @MarcosBueno: Envíame un mensaje desde mi Blog [www.rafaelacosta.net/Contact](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Contact) y cuéntame en lo que estás interesado. Ten en cuenta que yo estoy en España.